# Is it a straight line indeed?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]
Above a (normalized) graph of the function $f_1 = \arctan(1/\tan(x))$ over the interval $0\le x\le \pi$.

Is it really a straight line, $f_2=\frac\pi2-x$ ? neither Emacs' `calc` nor Wolfram's Alpha were able to simplify $f_1$ to $f_2$.

Comment: find the solve at different points,may be that will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $1\over \tan x$ = $\cot x$ = $\tan\left(\frac\pi2 - x\right)$

Therefore $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\tan x}\right) = \frac\pi2 - x$

(P.S: $0 < x < \pi$)

Comment: What if  $x=-\dfrac\pi3$

Answer (score 1):

$$\arctan\left(\frac1{\tan x}\right)=\arctan(\cot x)=\frac\pi2-\text{arccot}(\cot x)=\frac\pi2-x$$ if $0<x<\pi$ using [principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

Answer (score 1):

You may also show the relation by differentiating using chain rule:

$f'(x) = \left(\arctan \frac 1{\tan x}\right)' = \frac{1}{1+\frac 1{\tan^2x}}\cdot \left(-\frac 1{\tan^2x}\right)(1+\tan^2 x)=-1$

So, $\boxed{f(x) = -x + C}$.

For $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ you get $-\frac{\pi}{4} + C = \frac{\pi}{4} \Rightarrow \boxed{C = \frac{\pi}{2}}$

So, we have for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$: $\boxed{f(x) = -x + \frac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: Nice method indeed. (+1)